# Getting Information From Webpage

Tags: c#, screen-scraping

I'm not really a programmer (more of a scripter) and wrote a very quick script using AutoIt! to gather information from HP's website on a listing of computers we have.  I thought I would try to port it over to C# to make it a little more "professional".

The code reads in a file containg product code, serial number.  It then puts this information into a datagridview.  There are three columns, the third being the start date (what I'm looking for).

Below is what I have so far.  From here I'm lost as to what to do next.  The webpage does go to the next page, but I don't understand how to get the information I need (the first start date - which is the when the warranty started).  In AutoIt! it was frame 19 and then I parsed that.  I just don't quite know how to do it in C#.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
    private void runner(int i)
    {
        int j = i;
        bool loadFinished = false;

        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += delegate { loadFinished = true; };
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www11.itrc.hp.com/service/ewarranty/warrantyInput.do");

        while (!loadFinished )
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("productnumber").InnerText = dt.Rows[j][0].ToString();
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("serialnumber1").InnerText = dt.Rows[j][1].ToString();

        HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("SELECT");
        foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
        {
            if (elem.Name.ToString() == "country")
            {
                elem.SetAttribute("value", "US");
            }
        }

        int countelement = 0;
        HtmlElementCollection col = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT");
        foreach (HtmlElement element in col)
        {
            if (element.Name.ToString() == "")
            {
                if (countelement == 1)
                {
                    element.InvokeMember("click");
                }
                countelement++;
            }
        }
        dt.Rows[j][2] = "done";

    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

I really can't help you (because of I never did what you are doing now) but I think **[watin](http://watin.org/)** automation library can help you significantly

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  After the click event on the submit button, I needed to put a pause in to wait for the new page to load.  Even though I saw the new webpage, the program had already moved on to the next commands.  Looking at the variables in the debug I could see it was the old page.  Below is the code that I used.

After I figured out about the webpage loading, I already knew it was frame 19 to look at.  From there it was just a question of converting the string into an array of lines and then looping through looking for the first Start Date and pulling that information.

```
        private void runner(int i)
    {
        int j = i;
        bool loadFinished = false;

        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += delegate { loadFinished = true; };
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www11.itrc.hp.com/service/ewarranty/warrantyInput.do");

        while (!loadFinished )
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("productnumber").InnerText = dt.Rows[j][0].ToString();
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("serialnumber1").InnerText = dt.Rows[j][1].ToString();

        HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("SELECT");
        foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
        {
            if (elem.Name.ToString() == "country")
            {
                elem.SetAttribute("value", "US");
            }
        }

        int countelement = 0;
        HtmlElementCollection col = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT");
        foreach (HtmlElement element in col)
        {
            if (element.Name.ToString() == "")
            {
                if (countelement == 1)
                {
                    element.InvokeMember("click");
                    do
                    {
                        Application.DoEvents();
                    } while (webBrowser1.IsBusy);
                }
                countelement++;
            }
        }

        string output = "";
        int county = 0;
        HtmlElementCollection elly = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("TABLE");
        foreach (HtmlElement el in elly)
        {
            if (county == 19)
            {
                string[] lines = el.InnerText.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    if (line.IndexOf("Start Date") != -1)
                    {
                        output = line.ToString();
                        dt.Rows[j][2] = output.Remove(0, 10);
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }
            county++;
        }

    }
```